# How to send custom value to facebook iframe

Tags: php, facebook, iframe

I m working on a facebook iframe application. 
Facebook $_REQUEST response is as bellow:
Array
(
    [signed_request] => some value
    [PHPSESSID] => somevalue
    [fbs_251034681599274] => somevalue
)

but i want one more parameter to its REQUEST so i want its response like bellow

Array
(
    [fb] => some value
    [signed_request] => some value
    [PHPSESSID] => somevalue
    [fbs_251034681599274] => somevalue
)

and that fb key will be dynamically.
Please help me how can i do it.

Best Regards,
Krishna Karki

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify users you need to use fb authorization (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) and then you can get some unique ids

OR you can generate that keys on your server (where that iframe source is)

if you just want to send some data with interaction on that iframe, do it same as you do it on a non-iframe-facebook-app page.